# How to create a Subscription payment using Paypal client-side rest api?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

The [Client-side REST integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/) documentaion describes about creating a express checkout for one or more items.

How can i use the same for creating a subscription or Recurring payment? How should the following be modified?

```
 payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },
```

I found a similar [Rest api for Node](https://devblog.paypal.com/tutorial-subscriptions-plan/). Not sure how it would be on JS.

Comment: Client side integration is not meant for subscription purposes. You must use a server side implementation to be able to create subscription plans. And server side also makes sense because you always want to store the details that how much money you have received or how much is due and many more details

Comment: just FYI: the link you provided has server side implementation.

Comment: you are right. But I am unable to figure out how to change JSON used in [Server side request](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/create-express-checkout-payments/#request) so that a subscription is created.

Comment: I am not aware of any docs for that.

Comment: do you want to use only rest apis or you can work with client libraries?

Comment: no problems with that.

Comment: do you want a python example because it will be really hard to explain in comments

Comment: Python is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a billing plan:

```
billing_plan_attributes = {
                "name": PLAN_NAME_HERE,
                "description": PLAN_DESCRIPTION,
                "merchant_preferences": {
                    "auto_bill_amount": "yes", # yes if you want auto bill 
                    "cancel_url": "http://www.cancel.com", # redirect uri if user cancels payment
                    "initial_fail_amount_action": "continue",
                    "max_fail_attempts": "1",
                    "return_url": RETURN_URL,
                    "setup_fee": {
                        "currency": CURRENCY,
                        "value": VALUE # how much do you want to charge
                    }
                },
                "payment_definitions": [
                    {
                        "amount": {
                            "currency": request.form['currency'],
                            "value": request.form['amount']
                        },

                        "cycles": CYCLES, # how much time this subscription will charge user
                        "frequency": FREQ, # month, day
                        "frequency_interval": INTERVAL, # per month or per three month or so on
                        "name": NAME,
                        "type": TYPE
                    }
                ],
                "type": TYPE
            }
            billing_plan = BillingPlan(billing_plan_attributes)
            if billing_plan.create():
                print("success")
```

The attributes used have literal meaning here. Now since you have created a billing plan you need to give users some interface so that they can subscribe with it. Below is a sample code for this:

```
billing_agreement = BillingAgreement({
            "name": "Organization plan name",
            "description": "Agreement for " + request.args.get('name', ''),
            "start_date": (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
            "plan": {
                "id": request.args.get('id', '')
            },
            "payer": {
                "payment_method": "paypal"
            },
            "shipping_address": {
                "line1": "StayBr111idge Suites",
                "line2": "Cro12ok Street",
                "city": "San Jose",
                "state": "CA",
                "postal_code": "95112",
                "country_code": "US"
            }
        })
        if billing_agreement.create():
            for link in billing_agreement.links:
                if link.rel == "approval_url":
                    approval_url = link.href
```

In the last line you get the approval link which can be given to user.
Next you have to setup an endpoint which will be the callback url if user approves the payment.

```
billing_agreement_response = BillingAgreement.execute(payment_token)
```

payment_token is sent by paypal to your callback url.

Comment: whats the difference between PayPal setup fees and the amount in the json.

Comment: This is for scenarios when you want to take one time setup fees like one time registration fees or membership fees.